# SpriteKit App Crashing on iPhone 5s With Weird Error

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, crash-reports, testflight

I have a game that has been tested well on most devices it's been tested on, except it crashes on the only iPhone 5S I have access to. I've tried several things, among them deleting and reinstalling through TestFlight and installing an older version that works before installing the new one.

The crash log is this:

```
    SIGSEGV
    ArcadeDefense_iOS-[TFEventManager _getOldQueuePaths]

    Occurrences15
    Users1
    #   Binary Image Name   Address Symbol
    0   ArcadeDefense_iOS   0x10013de63 -[TFNetworkManager sendFile:toURL:withPriority:]
    1   ArcadeDefense_iOS   0x10013d537 -[TFEventManager _getOldQueuePaths]
    2   libsystem_platform.dylib    0x1912ffb1b _sigtramp
    3   SpriteKit   0x187532393 
    4   ArcadeDefense_iOS   0x1000d7d4b +[ALWrapper getSource3i:parameter:v1:v2:v3:] in ALWrapper.m on Line 1017
    5   ArcadeDefense_iOS   0x1000eff27 -[OALAudioTrack setSuspended:] in OALAudioTrack.m on Line 530
    6   ArcadeDefense_iOS   0x1000fc9d3 -[OALAudioTracks setPaused:] in OALAudioTracks.m on Line 123
    7   ArcadeDefense_iOS   0x1000fc543 +[OALAudioTracks allocWithZone:] in OALAudioTracks.m on Line 61
    8   ArcadeDefense_iOS   0x1000f718b -[OALAction runWithTarget:] in OALAction.m on Line 79
    9   Foundation  0x1852042cf __NSFireDelayedPerform
    10  CoreFoundation  0x18464ef53 
    11  CoreFoundation  0x18464ebc3 
    12  CoreFoundation  0x18464c8eb 
    13  CoreFoundation  0x18458d6cf CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    14  GraphicsServices    0x18a271c0b GSEventRunModal
    15  UIKit   0x1876befdb UIApplicationMain
    16  ArcadeDefense_iOS   0x1000f12f3 -[OALAudioTrack playAtTime:] in OALAudioTrack.m on Line 794
    17  libdyld.dylib   0x191187a9f 
    18      0xffffffffffffffff
```

I'm not sure entirely how to parse that, but it appears that it's having an issue with the method call

```
 [TFEventManager _getOldQueuePaths]
```

I've never heard of that before and google is no help. Help please!

Comment: Ask not what iPhone 5S can do for you.  Ask what iOS version can do for your device.

Comment: I probably should have specified, but was thinking that since SpriteKit and the 5s both require iOS 7 it wouldn't make a difference. However, I suppose it might not be obvious that the offending device was running 7.1. That being said, the app runs perfectly fine on iOS 7.0.4, 7.0.6, and 7.1 on every other device I've tried it on.